# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, google-app-engine, typeerror, keyword-argument

Below is the code that I use for the form to enter new cases into the GAE datastore. When I try to enter the form I get the type error below saying I am using an unexpected keyword argument. I am new to python and GAE does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
class Case(db.Model):
    user = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    title = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    facts = db.TextProperty()
    holding = db.TextProperty()
    rule_of_law = db.TextProperty()
    general_notes = db.TextProperty()
    key_concepts = db.TextProperty()        

class NewCase(Handler):
    def get(self,title="",
            facts="",
            holding="",
            rule_of_law="",
            general_notes="",
            key_concepts="",
            error=""):

        if self.user:
            self.render('newcase.html', title=title,
                        facts=facts,
                        holding=holding,
                        rule_of_law=rule_of_law,
                        general_notes=general_notes,
                        key_concepts=key_concepts,
                        error=error)
        else:
            self.redirect('/login')

def post(self):
    if not self.user:
        self.redirect('/')

    user = self.read_secure_cookie('user_id')    
    self.title = self.request.get('title')
    self.facts = self.request.get('facts')
    self.holding = self.request.get('holding')
    self.rule_of_law = self.request.get('rule_of_law')
    self.general_notes = self.request.get('general_notes')
    self.key_concepts = self.request.get('key_concepts')

    if self.title:
        c = Case(user = user,
                 title = self.title,
                 facts = self.facts,
                 holding = self.holding,
                 rule_of_law = self.rule_of_law,
                 general_notes = self.general_notes,
                 key_concepts = self.key_concepts)

        c.put()

        self.redirect('/%s' % c.key().id())

    else:
        error = "You must enter a title."
        self.render('newcase.html',title = self.title,
```

Error I'm getting:

```
File "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Web Apps\legalstudybuddy\main.py", line 233, in post
    key_concepts = self.key_concepts)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rule_of_law'
```

Comment: You have to show your handler

Comment: Somehow I seem to have fixed the problem. Not quite sure what I did but now it works.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're using Django Templates.
From: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/templates

> `template.render(path, template_values)` takes a file path to the template file and a dictionary of values, and returns the rendered text.

Note that `render` takes only two arguments: a path to a template, which you provided, and a single dictionary that has all the other values the template expects.

You gave it all those values as arguments, rather than packed into a dictionary.

Change:

```
self.render('newcase.html', title=title, facts=facts, holding=holding, ... )
```

to:

```
self.render('newcase.html', {title=title, facts=facts, holding=holding, ...})
```

and similarly for any other render calls.

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to be with the render call as I use other render calls with multiple variables and it works just fine. I think the type error is referring to an unexpected keyword argument while creating the GAE entity Case. Edit Line 233 is the line in c = Case(...)

Answer (score 1):

After running into the same problem, I found that my problem was in the webapp2.WSGIApplication Route definitions.

I had defined my Route as follows e.g.

```
webapp2.Route('/api/something/anEndpoint', handlers.SomethingEndpointHandler)
```

However, that route wasn't even reached because another Route that captured a regex keyword, defined earlier in the Route list, was being triggered instead:

```
webapp2.Route('/api/something/<something_id>', handlers.SomethingElseHandler)
```

This caused the TypeError in OP to appear with unexpected keyword argument 'something_id'.

A very difficult error to debug but hopefully this helps someone!